# Interpreting a frame number digit

Tags: identify-this-bike, giant

I'm trying to track down the owner of a Giant bike that I found by the roadside. The frame number on the bottom bracket looks like this: [image: Frame number]

My interpretation is `GX828648`, but I'm just a little bit uncertain about the penultimate digit. (The photo isn't great but it's not really easier to see in real life.) Do you agree with me that it looks like a 4?

Comment: I find it helpful to put some paint or quick erase magic marker onto the digits and then quickly rub them off, leaving residue in the "valleys." This makes poorly stamped serial numbers have greater contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck - there's a very high probability noone noted the serial number, or registered it anywhere that you can search.  Giant themselves might be able to tell you what shop sold it, but whether they kept records or not, who knows.

Your other option is to report it to the local police station as "found property" and after a month if the owner doesn't claim it then its yours legally.  We scored a nice tent that way that blew into our yard once, fully assembled but never pegged to the ground.

You can assume its probably not repainted, so is a Blue bike from new.

I'd agree with your reading of the digits.  Possibly the first character is a C or a Q or maybe an O, but the rest look exactly right.   G for Giant might make a lot of sense too.

Comment: The Norwegian bike registry gives GX###### as the standard pattern for Giant frame numbers, so I'm pretty sure about the reading now. The one month rule mentioned doesn't exist in my legislation, but the police can let people keep found items if they have a good reason to (otherwise you're supposed to hand them in for auctioning). I called today and they were happy to let me keep this cheap, rear wheel-less MTB. Might still contact Giant just to see if they have any information. Kind of fun to try to see what is possible.